# laravel vue button gets route but couldn't access the controller

Tags: laravel, vue.js, button, routes

i have a vue button to shortlist a user. when i click the button it could access the route but not the controller. i have a regular button inside a form tag and set action to the same url. everything works fine. but the only problem is that it redirects to a different blank page after processing.

vue button @click method

```
<template>

        <button class="button" @click="shortlistUser">Shortlist</button>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props:['userId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        methods:{

            shortlistUser(){
                axios.get('/shortlist/' + this.userId);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

web.php (this works)

```
Route::get('/shortlist/{user}', function (){
    $employer = Auth::User();
    $employer->candidates()->toggle([2]);

});
```

when i want to do the same via a controller, nothing happens.

```
Route::get('/shortlist/{user}', [Controllers\ShortlistController::class, 'index']);
```

controller

```
 public function index(User $user)
    {

        $employer = Auth::User();
        $employer->candidates()->toggle($user);

    }
```

Comment: your problem is that the axios request cant reach your controller ? 
try to add dd($user); in the top of index method

Comment: @MohamedAhmed i dont get anything. when i open the console i see
 app.js:1806 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/shortlist/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem exist in your axois call , userId send with undefined , be sure you send userId to the shortlist route . try to test your scenario by putting userid hard code like this : axios.get('/shortlist/2');

Comment: i did the same and still get the same error. :( im confused whats happening.

Comment: your error because you send undefined value with axios . try to clear cache and try again

Comment: after hard refresh axios.get('/shortlist/2'); works. now how do i call the props ?

Comment: can you edit your post , then add the component code ?

Comment: i dontunderstand. actually im learning for the first time. my blade file has this <shortlist_button userId="$user->user_id"></shortlist_button>

Comment: try this :- 
<shortlist_button :userId=" '{{ $user->user_id }}' "></shortlist_button>

Comment: no it doesnt work. i tried several ways. im using laravel 8

Comment: your current problem is that , user_id sent with null value to your component props. 
try this :-
<shortlist_button userId="'{{ $user->user_id }}'"></shortlist_button>

Comment: it doesnt work. but defenitely {{ $user->user_id }} has the value 2. and i did this too. <shortlist_button userId="2"></shortlist_button> still its same (undefined)

Comment: ok , share your component code ( this component  => shortlist_button )

Comment: its a vue component. for the button.
<button class="button" @click="shortlistUser">Shortlist</button>

Comment: please check my question above. i have posted the full code from component

Comment: ok , try to send data to this component with kebab case , like this :- <shortlist_button user-id="2"></shortlist_button>

Comment: yes this works :) everything is ok now. thank you very much. thanks for your time. this made me go crazy.